# Deleting branches which name contains weird characters

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I use Git Bash, and by mistake I created a branch named -D. 
After having search with Google, I tried either

```
git branch -d -- -D
```

obtaining

```
error: branch '-D' not found.
```

and I also tried to remove it from gitk but without success.

On the other hand, I have noticed that the branch name changes if I type `git branch` from the console or if I display it on gitk. For instance, the branch is  -D in the console, but it is named with weird characters on gitk.

[Branch name obtained with git log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY2rd.png)

[Branch name displayed in gitk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayibv.png)

At this point I copied/paste the weird name from gitk to the console, and I issued

```
git branch -d â?"D
```

without success.

However, I got the warning message: *"Warning: Your console font probably doesn't support Unicode. If you experience strange characters in the output, consider switching to a TrueType font such as Lucida Console!"*

As last attempt, I tried to remove the branch from gitk, but I get a popup window saying "error: branch *yet another weird and longer name* not found".

This time, I cannot copy and paste *yet another weird and longer name* from the pop up box to the console, since I cannot copy from a pop up window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warp the branch name with quotes

```
git branch -D "-D"
```

---

#### Other options

If you have it locally you can simply remove the file from your `.git/ref/heads/branch_name` folder and delete it.

Comment: I have it only locally. Anyways: `git branch -D "-D"` didn't work. I got `fatal: branch name required`.  I tried with several quote signs and without any quote sign, all without success. 2. Canceling `.git/ref/heads/-D` did the job.Thanks!

Comment: This answer does not make sense. The quotes do precisely nothing here - the shell will strip them off, and git will see exactly the same parameters as without them. Quotes only make sense to protect shell meta characters (like space), which is not the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the gitk screenshot, the hyphen in the branch name is not a regular ASCII hyphen (ASCII code 45), but an [Em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash), encoded as UTF-8, and then interpreted (by gitk) with character encoding [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (aka "Codepage 1252").

The Em dash has Unicode code point 2014, which translates to the UTF-8 byte sequence `E2 80 94`. If you interpret these three bytes as Windows-1252, you obtain the three characters â€” (the Unicode code points "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX", "EURO SIGN", "RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK") - which is what gitk shows (apparently gitk defaults to character encoding Windows-1252 on your system).

---

To delete this branch, you need to grab an Em dash somewhere. One way is to start Windows Wordpad (or Microsoft Word), then type <kbd>Alt</kbd>
<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> (you must use the numeric keypad!).

That enters an Em dash. Copy that character, then paste it into your git shell into this command, before the "D":

> git branch -d 'D'

Enter, and you're done :-).

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), you should now be able to [delete that branch from `gitk` directly](http://wiki.seas.harvard.edu/geos-chem/index.php/Branching), considering it has learned to deal with Unicode characters in branch names.

[image: http://wiki.seas.harvard.edu/geos-chem/images/6/6e/GitKDeleteBranch.png]

See [commit e244588](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e244588eb6ceef86a6a183b3bb032960e26033bb) (10 Sep 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
See [commit a99bc27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a99bc27aec74071aa1e9ecaa12c642e88e377165) (15 Dec 2019), and [commit f177c49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f177c49a97d16aab490aa34fa52e113c21de4a1f) (02 Nov 2019) by [Роман Донченко (`SpecLad`)](https://github.com/SpecLad).
See [commit 2faa6cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2faa6cdc5e4d1d5fd27512994f002fc2640b1949) (09 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
See [commit c1a6345](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1a63459ed7364bb03e0549c1f042bca469d278f) (15 Oct 2019) by [Eric Huber (`echuber2`)](https://github.com/echuber2).
See [commit b8b6095](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8b60957ce91b237b7f8925a3126b2662d3fcf41) (12 Dec 2019) by [Beat Bolli (`bbolli`)](https://github.com/bbolli).
See [commit e2b9cb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2b9cb1c5a45290f568681862fb27714d6e4e52b) (03 Oct 2020), and [commit e272a77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e272a77964d95e2fd8b3b47b7f3840ed3e42b81c) (23 Jan 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 6cd8049](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cd80496e9d3694825ec941663b65c9516102289) (03 Oct 2020) by [Paul Mackerras (`paulusmack`)](https://github.com/paulusmack).
See [commit 113ce12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/113ce1243f0bcd870b24ff22aca212575027f79f) (11 Feb 2020) by [Stefan Dotterweich (`stefandtw`)](https://github.com/stefandtw).
See [commit d4247e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4247e06027da5b3ac299fbba3a7443a919ca0ff) (07 Dec 2019) by [Kazuhiro Kato (`kkato233`)](https://github.com/kkato233).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0cf28f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cf28f6d4775ca304e3e2028c2645c600e869641), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`gitk`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4247e06027da5b3ac299fbba3a7443a919ca0ff): fix branch name encoding error
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kazuhiro Kato</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Paul Mackerras</sup>

> After "[`git checkout -b '漢字'`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cf28f6d4775ca304e3e2028c2645c600e869641/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L147-L149)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--bltnewbranchgt))</sup> to create a branch with UTF-8 character in it, "`gitk`" shows the branch name incorrectly, as it forgets to turn the bytes read from the "[`git show-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cf28f6d4775ca304e3e2028c2645c600e869641/Documentation/git-show-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref))</sup> command into Unicode characters.